# I can't call a parametric SPARQL query from an internal Prolog predicate

Tags: prolog, sparql, semantic-web

I am going crazy with the following problem:

I have a predicate **makeQuery/3** that build a parametric SPARQL query to interrogate DBpedia, this one:

```
makeQuery(Place, Query, Row) :-   %% e.g. Place = '"Rome"'
    atomic_list_concat( [ 'select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ;',
      ' rdfs:label ', Place, '@it.}'], Query),
    sparql_query(Query, Row, [ host('dbpedia.org'), path('/sparql/')] ).
```

As you can see it work well in the Prolog shell, in fact I can pass it a specific **Place** parameter and then it check if this is a place using DbPedia, this is the output in my Prolog shell:

```
[debug]  ?- makeQuery('"Roma"', Query, Row).
Query = 'select COUNT(*) where {?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label "Roma"@it.}',
Row = row(literal(type('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer', '1'))).
```

As you can see the parameter have to be passed in this way: **'"Roma"'**, I think that this means that Roma is an atom (or is it wrong interpretation?)

Ok, this work well infact my result (**Row**) find an occurrence so, for me, Roma is a place !!!

Now I am finding a big problem: **This makeQuery/3 predicate have to be used by others predicates and not in the Prolog shell** and I can't use it into an other predicate.

I have create the following **execute/2** predicate that try to use it:

```
execute([FirstToken|Tail], TokenValue, OccurrencesPlaces) :-
    write(FirstToken),
    arg(2, FirstToken, TokenValue),
    atom_codes(Atom, TokenValue),
    makeQuery(Atom, Query, OccurrencesPlaces),
    write(OccurrencesPlaces).
```

This predicate take a list of tokens (for me a token is something like: **t(1, [82, 111, 109, 97])** that have a **t: functor**, a **identifier progressive number** and the **token content that is a list of ASCII rappresenting a String that is a word)**

For example the previous token have 1 as identifier and its content rappresent the string **Roma** (that is a place so the query will found an occurrence)

Ok, so this predicate put in the **TokenValue** variable the string and execute the previous **makeQuery/2** predicate passing to it my **TokenValue** value (in the previous example the string **Roma**)

Now in the prolog shell I do:

```
[debug]  ?- SystemTokenized = [t(1, [82, 111, 109, 97])].
SystemTokenized = [t(1, [82, 111, 109, 97])].
```

and now I call the **execute/3** predicate passing to it SystemTokenized:

```
[debug]  ?- execute($SystemTokenized, TokenValue, OccurrencePlaces).
t(1,[82,111,109,97])
false.
```

As you can see seems don't work well because I am passing the string **Roma** to the query as parameter but I think that there is some problem because it is not an atom or something like this...

I am trying to solve from some hours but I can't find a solution

So my problem is: how can call the **execute/3** predicate from another predicate that take the parameter like in the previous example?

Comment: `atom_codes(A, "Roma"), atomic_list_concat(['"', A, '"'], Result).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do prefer [format](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2)/2 when I have to - well - format complex strings.
I tackled your problem with

```
execute([FirstToken|_Tail], TokenValue, OccurrencesPlaces) :-
    arg(2, FirstToken, TokenValue),
    format(atom(Place), '"~s"', [TokenValue]),
    makeQuery(Place, _Query, OccurrencesPlaces),
    write(OccurrencesPlaces).
```

What's suggested by Daniel should work as well.